# ROS Package For IMU Positional Movement?

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a ROS package that uses IMU data to determine positional movement (for example, relative to the start location), based on the existing IMU data like acceleration?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232568/ros-package-for-imu-positional-movement?/) by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You likely can setup a few state estimation packages out there for purely integrating IMU data. [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) has the most complete documentation on how to perform a corresponding setup I believe.

Note that unless you have a really expensive IMU (let's say upwards of 10000 US$), this kind purely IMU-based approach will quickly diverge from the true pose of the sensor and will be of limited usefulness.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on 2016-04-22**:
I thought that robot_localization would have this implemented as well, but I didn't find anything that gives you the positional movement data from that package--not sure if there is something I missed?

I am working in planar space and fusing with wheel odometer, so hoping it will be more feasible

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-04-22**:
If you configure things according to http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/Sensor%20Configuration the odom message robot_localization puts out should contain pose and velocity information computed from the specified inputs.

**Comment by [bzhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/26225/bzhan/) on 2016-04-22**:
I get no output when I run rostopic echo /odometry/filtered (after launching the package with all possible launch files). I started my IMU with rosrun, and the /imu messages are printing out fine. I am wondering if I did something wrong?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-04-24**:
Laucnhing all possible launch files is not necessarily the best approach. You should make sure you have one correct launch file and work on getting that :) Have you verified robot_localization actually subscribed to your IMU data?